# How does an access transfer control function in a communications network work mathematically?

Tags: network-access-control

I read [here](https://www.google.ch/patents/WO2014008913A1?cl=en&dq=INTERCEPTION&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi73p2Z1rvRAhWCORQKHQEgDhUQ6AEIUzAG) about Lawful interception in a communications network.
 There is a function called *access transfer control function*.
What is it in mathematical terms?

I don't want understand the process (I know how it is implemented like information system), I need to understand if it can be written like a formula, graph or topological space, a domain etc

> In order to enhance service experience during the inter domain handover, two additional network nodes are provided. An Access Transfer Control Function (ATCF) 16 located between a Proxy-Call Session Control Function (P-CSCF) 1 7 and a Serving-Call Session Control Function (S-CSCF) 18 and is used as a signalling anchor point. An Access Transfer Gateway (ATGW) 19 is located in the IMS network 14 between the UE 9 and a MSS or MSC 20, and is used for media anchoring

I need to translate this process like a mathematical model, inference or some vector space.